# JTable Cell data remaining the same between switching of table model data

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

The issue I am having is that since I have used camickr TableCellListener found [here](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/), the data for a single table cell will not change if the data changes for the entire table model. The user must have the table cell selected for editing in order for this to happen. I know I need to stop cell editing but how?

I can't seem to get this to work....

```
table.getCellEditor().cancelCellEditing()
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: If you are suggesting that the editor remains active when you change the TableModel, then yes you should stop editing before you change the TableModel. So I'm guessing the user would click on a button to cause the TableModel to change. So the cancelCellEditing() method should be invoked in the ActionListener added to the button before the model is changed.

Comment: if (table.getCellEditor() != null) {
    table.getCellEditor().cancelCellEditing();
     }

Comment: That is all I had to do inside the button as camickr suggested